# Performing custom authorization in Spring annotated controller

Tags: spring, security, rest, spring-mvc, authorization

I'm getting started at building REST APIs with Spring annotated controllers.

My question is very simple: how to perform authentication/authorization in a common place rather than the APIs?

Being an expert C# developer I usually create a custom `FilterAttribute` for my controllers in order to implement any required authentication code.

I'm not going to use `@Secured` attribute because I work on custom REST authorization based on custom HTTP headers. I have understood that `@Secured` works with predefined roles, or perhaps I didn't understand its usage well.

Does Spring offer annotations to perform early filtering of Controllers working on the `HttpRequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a filter-based authentication and authorization plugin at the web container level, provided by Spring Security. However, you can also apply security annotations to the controllers. . . Behind the scenes this uses Aspect Oriented programming to modularize the security concern. Take a look at Spring Security and AOP.

Once you understand a little about the AOP side of things you can customize the authorization however you like - role-based, time of day, whatever - this can be driven by custom annotations.

Comment: Could you address me to a more specific subset of functions where to look (i.e. documentation, tutorial)? I surely want to apply security annotation to controller, but I haven't found any so far that allows me to define my custom authorization handler. No matter what it returns (true/false, exception, etc) I need to parse HttpRequest

Comment: The problem is that its actually quite a big topic, and I don't know where to point you first. . If you have the time, then Spring in Action is a fantastic book. (You can skim chapters for topics you're already familiar with - like DI, focusing in on AOP). . Here's a tutorial on custom annotations: http://blog.novoj.net/2012/03/27/combining-custom-annotations-for-securing-methods-with-spring-security/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm also considering the following approach: interceptors :) http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorial/spring-mvc/spring-interceptor-example

Comment: AOP is essentially an interceptor pattern, so anything you do with the custom intercept point in MVC could be done with AOP. . powerful, but the learning curve is steeper, and if you just need to get it done. . .